# Incorrect string value: '\xE6\x8E\x92\xE5\xBA\x8F' for column 'title' at row 1

Tags: python, django, unicode, ascii

I am learning python and django these days and today I want to write something  insteresting. So I write a script that download some data from [this site](http://pythontip.sinaapp.com/). Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import sys  
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
import chardet
from django.http import HttpResponse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
from getdata.models import trel

class Rel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.result = None
        self.codenu = None
        self.title = None
        self.user = None

def getdata(request):
    page = 1
    while page <= 1:
        url = "http://pythontip.sinaapp.com/coding/code_record?page=" + str(page)
        html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        content = html.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content).find('tbody')
        for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
            r = trel()
            td_list = tr.find_all('td')
            r.codenu = td_list[0].get_text()
            r.title = td_list[1].get_text()
            r.user = td_list[2].get_text()
            r.result = td_list[3].get_text()
            print "The encoding is %s and Type is %s" %   (chardet.detect(r.codenu),type(r.codenu))
    r.save()
    page += 1
```

Notice the print sentence. In my machine I got this:

```
The encoding is {'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'} and Type is <type 'unicode'>
```

I feel very strange because the encoding and the type conficts. Could anyone where the wrong is?

And the bug trace are here:

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/getdata/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'getdata')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/leo/challenge/challenge/getdata/views.py" in getdata
  25.         for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):

Exception Type: AttributeError at /getdata/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Comment: You are trying to put this value in the title 输出字符奇数位置的字符串,
Thats why you are getting this error.

Comment: What's the relationship of the title with the body of the question?

Comment: @Silwestpl I think I got the error because I inserted the data into mysql. By the way, my mysql charsets are all utf-8

Comment: @PauloBu The title is the error message I have got and I believe that many people got this error so maybe it be friendly with search engine ;)

Comment: @Jerry Yes but I mean, your question asks about an output, it doesn't yield any error AFAIK.

Comment: @PauloBu With keyword "Incorrect string value" I search and got a lot of result ... so I think this maybe a common question, at least in my language(Chinese).

Answer (score 0):

Can you add all bug trace?

This error is probably cose by your database coding configuration (MySQL).

Comment: This looks like a comment, aren't you able to comment the question?

Answer (score 0):

I try to drop my database, then create it again and I find the problem solved. You should delete your database after you change the charset of MySQL.